# SQL Querying Database

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have this following query
 `"select abc from table where val = 1"`
The result i got was

```
 [{abc=5}]
```

However, I **need just the integer value 5** from the result **instead of the array[{abc=5}]**.
Anyone have any idea on how to do this? thanks
*My friend told me that I will need to use substring to get just the 5 out from the [{abc=5}], but i have completely no clue on how to work on it. Any help will be appreciated!

*edited

Comment: Use `count(*)` instead of `column`?

Comment: Ask your question properly, what are you trying to do?

Comment: What you want to get is its just the count of total rows where cloumn 'val' = 1 or the values from column  'column' where value of cloumn 'val' = 1

Comment: the value without the '=' and brackets [{

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

Assume the integer value comes between = and } symbols

```
select substring(abc,charindex('=',abc)+1,len(abc)-charindex('}',abc))
```

## [SQL fiddle  demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb6ab/2)

Comment: "Argument data type bigint is invalid for argument 1 of substring function. S1000/8116" This is the error message I got. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

for the count of the column

```
 select count(column) from table where val=1
```

Comment: Nono I need the value of it not the count of it, sorry guys for not being specific

Comment: @user1718890 what datatype is that column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregate function count

`select count(1) from table where val = 1`

Use count(1) because it is optimized compare to count(*)

Answer (score 0):

So, you need the exact value from the

[{abc=5}]

and you need to retrieve the value '5'? Am I right to say that?